# All rows of specific column in dataset

Tags: c#, vb.net, dataset, datarow

I have a DataSet that looks like this :

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | ... |   Z  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | ... |  26  |
|11 |22 |33 |44 |55 |66 |77 |88 |99 | ... | 2626 |
|111|222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999| ... |262626|
```

Values *not related*.  I just have *a lot* of columns.

I would like to **go through all rows for a specific column**. 
Is it possible without going though all columns ? Because right now the only thing I can think of is this (let's say I want all rows for column D)

C#

```
foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows)
   if(row.Column == myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns("D"))
      MessageBox.Show("I'm in Column B");
```

VB

```
For Each row As DataRow In myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
If row.Column Is myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns("D") Then
MessageBox.Show("I'm in Column B")
End If
Next
```

But this would loop through all columns. I would like to use a collection like 
`myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns("D").Rows` but it does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataRow` has an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) that you can use:

```
foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    Console.WriteLine("I'm in Column B: " + row["D"]);
```

You can access it via [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) or [ordinal-index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx) of the field. The [third overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035.aspx) can be used if you have a reference of  `DataColumn` and is used by the others after the column was found. If you don't want to "search" for the column(although the effort is negligible) use this:

```
DataColumn col = myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["D"];
foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("I'm in Column B: " + row[col]);
```

But you could also use Linq, for example if you want to sum all values in this column:

```
int dTotal = myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("D"));
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But this would still go trhough **all rows** in my databse to see if it is of `Column B`. So the perfomance is the same. Unless i'm wrong.

Comment: Also I know about this approach but unfortunately LINQ is not and option here. (Vb.Net 2.0 work environment) :-( !

Comment: So obvious when you see it... Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In an immaginary grid you scroll the rows vertically and access the column horizontally

```
foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows)
{
   // At this point the row iterator point to a row 
   // where all the values in the schema columns are available
   // Indexing with the column name will result in related value 
   MessageBox.Show(row["D"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: WOuld this be as ressource conssuming as my first approach since it still have to check **all rows** to see if it fits the `row["D"]`criteria ?

Comment: What is your criteria?. The best performance could be obtained modifying the query that returns the values from the database, but you could use the DataTable.Select method to extract only the rows required

Comment: I forgot there is no context in my question. I have a field in a column that is splitted into 2 languages by a `,`. So I want to test if it's in french or in english and keep part of the column field. But in a perfect design, I guess this should be done in my query right ?

Comment: Now it is a bit clearer. Probably you could return only the rows that contains the particular substring using the LIKE operator at the database level, or, if the database allows, split the string and check with some kind of storeprocedure. Otherwise I think you don't have any possibilities that getting all the resultset and work via code.

Comment: @Steve: `row["D"]` will cause the indexer to search for a column with the name `D`. That's what OP wants to avoid. You need to use the `DataColumn` overload.

Comment: You're right I was a bit concerned about whether I should import a column with both values OR send the program's currenct culture to my stored procedure and filter the column directly in SQL. I'm still new to programming and this kind of design confuses me. Thanks :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see, not sure but I don't think there is too much to gain here. However you were right to get the reference to the column before entering the loop